# Look through named ranges and print values to new sheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am relatively new to JavaScript, so please bear with me.

I have a seating chart in a google spreadsheet which labels the desk number and name of the person who sits there in two adjacent cells via a named range. I want my code to loop through all the named ranges, and get the values for the desk numbers and people and spit it into a new sheet in two columns-desk number in one column and the user name in another. A major issue I am having is that some desk number/user ranges are vertical (ex: desk_1 = Sheet1!F6:F7 where F6 is the desk number and F7 is the user) and some ranges are horizontal (ex: desk_2 = Sheet1!G2:H2 where G2 is the usere and H2 is the desk number) so I am not sure how to search from multiple directions. Here's a bit of my code, which is currently not working. Any advise would be greatly appreciated!!

```
enter code here
function findSeats() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var wbk = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 

var rng_convention = "desk_"; 
var desk_name = rng_convention; 

var users = new Array();

for ( var i = 0; i <= 1000; i++) { 
  desk_name = rng_convention; 
  desk_name = desk_name + i; 

  var rng = wbk.getRangeByName(desk_name); 

if( !rng ) { 
  continue; }
else { 
  var vals = rng.getValues(); 
  var k = 0; 

  if(vals.length == 1) {
    //look left right horizontally for user
    if(vals[0][0] == i) { 
      // create a user for this named range. 
      var user = new Object(); 

      user.name = vals[0][1]; 
      user.position = vals[0][0]; 
      users[k] = user; 
      k++;
    }
    else { 
      //look right left horizontally for user
      if (vals [0][1] == i){
      // create the user for this named range. 
      var user = new Object();

      user.name = vals[0][0]; 
      user.position = vals[0][1]; 
      users[k] = user; 
      k++;
      }
    }
  } 
/*      else {
    /* something is wrong, I need to look up-down, and then down up for users */
  }
 } 
return users; 

};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were definitely on the right track. Your only real bug is that you're setting `var k = 0` inside a loop, but trying to increment it in the same loop. The result is that you get just one user.

You want to be able to determine if a desk / user pairing is arranged horizontally or vertically. To do that, you're checking the `length` of the two-dimensional array returned by `.getValues()`, which works well. No problem there.

In your question, you mention two arrangements of desk / user pairs, but it appears in your code that you are concerned about four, because in the horizontal orientation you'd coded, you're looking for the location of the desk number, and assuming the name is in the opposite cell. That works, as long as the desk number is always a match for the range name. (You could just check to see if the value is a `number`, instead.)

So, here's the changes I've made to make this work.

- First, got rid of `k` altogether, and relied on `push()` to build the `users` array - much simpler and less error-prone.
- I moved the user object creation outside of the if-then-else block that tests for orientation, and set the desk number at the same time. (That value needn't be read from the spreadsheet, since it's already a looping value.)
- I completed the handling for vertical orientations, mirroring the cleaned-up horizontal handling. (You know... you could further optimize this, but it would lose clarity.)
- Added comments, and tidied indenting! (Actually, did that as I was code inspecting.)

Here's the resulting, functioning code.

```
function findSeats() {
  var wbk = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 

  var rng_convention = "desk_"; 
  var desk_name = rng_convention; 

  var users = new Array();

  for ( var i = 0; i <= 1000; i++) { 
    desk_name = rng_convention + i; 

    var rng = wbk.getRangeByName(desk_name); 

    if ( !rng ) { 
      // No matching range name
      continue; 
    }
    else { 
      var vals = rng.getValues(); 

      // create a user for this named range. 
      var user = new Object(); 
      user.position = i; 

      var valsLength = vals.length;
      // Check orientation of the range:
      //    Horizontal...  vals.length == 1 (row)
      //    Vertical means vals.length == 2 (rows)
      if(vals.length == 1) {
        // Check whether we have desk / user, or user / desk
        if(vals[0][0] == i) { 
          // desk / user
          user.name = vals[0][1]; 
        }
        else { 
          // user / desk
          user.name = vals[0][0]; 
        }
      }
      else {
        // vals.length == 2
        // Check whether we have desk / user, or user / desk
        if(vals[0][0] == i) { 
          // desk / user
          user.name = vals[1][0]; 
        }
        else { 
          // user / desk
          user.name = vals[0][0]; 
        }
      }

      // Add this user to our array
      users.push(user);
    }
  }
  // Return array of user objects
  return users; 
};
```

### Sample Data

[image: sample data]

### Debug Output

[image: debug output]

### Edit: Record all collected data in a spreadsheet

To answer the follow-up question, it's straight-forward to get all the collected desk & user information into a spreadsheet. To prepare for the `.setValues()` function, we need to convert our objects to a 2-d Array, which is easy. Alternatively, the previous code could be refactored to generate an array in the first place.

Here's how we can perform the conversion, and write all the data a sheet. If the named sheet does not exist, we'll create it first - otherwise, we'll just replace the previous contents.

```
// Record all desk / user data to a (new) sheet
function recordAllDeskUsers() {
  var users = findSeats();
  var userArray = new Array();
  userArray.push(["Desk #","User Name"]);

  for (var i in users) {
    var thisUser = [users[i].position,users[i].name];
    userArray.push(thisUser);
  }

  // Open the target sheet - if it doesn't exist, insert it.
  var userSheetName = "All Desks";
  var userSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(userSheetName);
  if (!userSheet) {
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().insertSheet(userSheetName)
    userSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(userSheetName);
  }

  // Clear the sheet, then write our collected values to it.
  userSheet.clear();
  userSheet.getRange(1, 1, userArray.length, userArray[0].length).setValues(userArray);
}
```

Comment: This is great, thank you so much! But now, how do I print the range values to a new sheet in which the desk numbers are listed in column A and the users are in column B? Will I need to transpose the range pairs that are not in the desk_#/user orientation? Not quite sure how to go about doing that.

Comment: Not 'transpose', but 'convert', and it's quite easy. I've edited the answer with that. Because the various arrangements were all rendered into objects, the differences have been dealt with.

Comment: Interesting- some desks have multiple numbers. Ex. desks 627 and 628 belong to user1, the named range desk_627 = Sheet1!M29:M30, where the user cell "user1" is in cell M29, and the position cell contains "627 628" in cell M30 (ie user on top, position on bottom). This spits the desk number (627) and user1 correctly into the 'All Desks' sheet. But if the position cell is M29 and the user cell is M30 (ie position on top, user on bottom), then in the 'All Desks' sheet, desk 627 says the user is "627 628".. any ideas why this is happening? Thanks for ALL your help, seriously!

Comment: That's happening because of the way the location of the desk# cell is done; you're looking for [0][0] to equal the loop variable. If it's not equal, the content is assumed to be the name. When the double value shows up, it's not equal to the loop var, but it's also not the name. Further, the value from the sheet isn't a number, because it has a space in it. You could coerce the values to strings and do a substring match instead, or fix the data.

Comment: Instead of `if(vals[0][0] == i)`, you'd need `if ((((''+vals[0][0]).split(/[\s,]+/)).indexOf(''+i)) != -1)`, to find `i` in a list of space-or-comma-deliminated numbers. If you want the *list* of desk numbers to show up in 'All Desks', then the assignment to `user.position` needs to be changed to get the cell containing the list.

Comment: Yes, that last fix was just what I was looking for! Thank you again, you're a life saver!